# Importing JSON data in Highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts

I have read lots of references to this same item but I am still confused. I have added my code.

In the attached code I have two plots. `plot_1` uses data defined within the page and `plot_2` is identical but uses JSON imported data. `plot_1` works fine, and `plot_2` does not. There are a lot of different versions of importing JSON data on this forum, and I have tried to emulate a number of them without success. I am using this code on an embedded system. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

```
<script>
$(function () { 
        $('#plot_1').highcharts({
        chart: {
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 3,
        borderColor: '#a1a1a1',
                type: 'line',
        marginBottom: 30
        },
        title: {
                text: 'Battery Voltage and Current'
        },
        xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 2, 26),      // Jan = 0
        pointInterval: 60 * 1000 * 15,      // 15 minutes
        labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x:  0,
        y:  16
        }
        },

        yAxis: [{               // Primary axis (left)
        startOnTick: true,
                title: {
                text: 'Volts',
        style: {
            color: '#89A54E'
        }
                },
        labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3,
        y: 0,
        style: {
            color: '#89A54E'
        }
        },
        min: 6,
        max: 16

        },{                 // Secondary axis (right)
        opposite: true,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Amps',
        style: {
            color: '#4572A7'
        }
                },
        labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 3,
        y: 0,
        style: {
            color: '#4572A7'
        }
        },
        min: -0.5,
        max:  0.5
    }],

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series : {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
        }
    },

        series: [{
            name: 'Volt',
        color: '#89A54E',
                data:  [12.4,   12.4,    12.4,    12.2,    12.0,    11.9,    11.9,    11.8,    11.6,    11.4,    11.1,    10.9,     11.4,     11.5,     11.7,     11.9,     12.2,     12.4,     12.4,     12.4]
        }, {
                name: 'Amp',
        color: '#4572A7',
        yAxis: 1,
                data: [-0.1, -0.2, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.3, -0.4, -0.3, -0.4, -0.4, -0.3, -0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.1]
        }]
        });
});
    </script>   


    <script>
$(function () {

    var data1 = [], data2 = [];

    function requestData1() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "sig0.jsn",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data1) {
                alert (data1);
                this.series[0].setData(data1);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }

    function requestData2() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "sig2.jsn",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data2) {
                alert (data2);
                this.series[0].setData(data2);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }


        $('#plot_2').highcharts({
        chart: {
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 3,
        borderColor: '#a1a1a1',
                type: 'line',
        marginBottom: 30,
        events: {
        load: requestData1,
        load: requestData2
        }
        },
        title: {
                text: 'Received Signal Strength'
        },
        xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 2, 26),      
        pointInterval: 60 * 1000 * 15,
        labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x:  0,
        y:  16
        }
        },

        yAxis: {                // Primary axis (left)
        startOnTick: true,
                title: {
                text: 'Strength (db)'
                },
        labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3,
        y: 0

        },
        min: -40,
        max: 0

    },

    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        floating: true,
        x: 50,
        y: 45
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series : {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
        }
    },

        series: [{
            name: 'Device A',
        color: '#89A54E',
                data: data1
        },{
            name: 'Device B',
        color: '#4572A7',
                data: data2
        }]

        });

});
    </script>
```

The JSON file data loks like this.

```
{
"data" : [-25, -23, -15, -16, -26, -24, -26, -28, 29, -16, -22, -24, -22, -17, -21, -25, -21, -22, -23, -22]
}
```

In the end I will have the x-axis time data paired with the y-axis data because it is likely I will miss some time intervals in the data recording, so if you could please consider that in the answer. Overall I want to plot the data from 4 sensors.

Comment: What's your actual question? The process is to create your chart inside the success callback of `$.getJSON`

Answer (score 0):

You should move chart inilazize inside ajax calling, because in your case ajax and highcharts defininition is run "in the same time".

As a result is should looks like:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "sig2.jsn",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data2) {
            alert (data2);
            this.series[0].setData(data2);
            $('#plot_2').highcharts({
                            //parameters
            });
        },
        cache: false
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried this but it did not seem to work. When I do what you have advised, the entire chart does not appear. When I use the code I previously posted, I get the basic plot, but without data. With my code I also get a popup window saying sewage from webpage' [object Object]